# Shell Script: Replace text

Tags: shell, sed, replace

machineName=machine1

Replace:
MACHINEDOTS="'uname -n'"
to
MACHINEDOTS="machine1"

I tried the following sed cmd,

sed 's/MACHINEDOTS="'uname -n'"/MACHINEDOTS="'$machineName'"/g'  tmp
mv -f tmp path

Error displayed:
sed: invalid option -- '"'

Answer (score 1):

When I try to run your example on Mac OS X 10.7, I get an "unterminated substitute pattern" because you used a double quote " instead of either a single quote ' or a backquote `.

Replacing the double quote with a single quote and getting rid of the garbage after tmp (did you mean && mv -f tmp path ?) like this:

```
sed 's/MACHINEDOTS=''uname -n''/MACHINEDOTS="'$machineName'"/g' tmp
```

works, but I'm not 100% sure whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> sed 's/MACHINEDOTS="'uname -n'"/MACHINEDOTS="'$machineName'"/g' tmp mv -f tmp path

Do you mean to evaluate `uname -n`? It will need to be in back ticks. 
Like so:

```
$ sed 's/\(MACHINEDOTS="\)'`uname -n`'"/\1'$machineName'"/g'
```